# Separable polynomials by Bourbaki

Tags: field-theory

In Bourbaki, Algebra, V, 37, we have Proposition 3, which states that:
Let $f$ be a non-zero polynomial in $K[X]$ and let $\Omega$ be an 
algebraically closed extension of $K$. The following conditions are equivalent:

c) There exists an extension $L$ of $K$ such that $f$ splits in $L[X]$ into a product of distinct polynomials of degree $\leq 1$.

d) The roots of $f$ in $\Omega$ are simple.

I am very confused by c). Let us consider $f(X) = (2X-2)(X-1) \in \mathbb{R}[X]$: We have that $f$ satisfies c) but not d). The proof by Bourbaki to show that c) implies d) begins as follows: "Under the hypothesis c) there exist an element $\lambda \not= 0$  in $L$ and distinct elements $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ of $L$ such that $f(X) = \lambda (X - \alpha_1) ... (X - \alpha_n)$." With my $f$, we have $f(X) = 2 (X-1) (X-1)$ and the $\alpha_i$'s are not distinct. Is it a mistake in Bourbaki ("monic" is missing) or did I misunderstand something here?

Comment: Maybe they mean *non associate* polynomials?

Comment: It seems they want to be smart and they outsmarted themselves. It's much simpler to assume $f$ is monic and state condition c as “there exists an extension $L$ of $K$ such that $f$ splits in $L[X]$ into a product of distinct monic polynomials of degree one”.

Comment: This certainly does look like they just missed the word ‘monic’ somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps they mean $2$ is a polynomial of degree zero, and the factorisation you give is not complete? I don't know the text, but degree $\le 1$ suggests the possibility.